# hg convert from svn, need to pull branches from more than one place

Tags: mercurial

I have a few odd issues with a svn repository I'm trying to convert to hg. Our repository looks more or less like this.

```
proj_root  ___ trunk
       \  \___ tags
        \_____ branches __A
                   \   \__B
                    \_____Q __ C
                          \___ D
```

Ideally I could specify `--config convert.svn.branches=branches;branches/Q` or somesuch nonesense. (Q does not contain a branch in itself, just the two "sub branches".

I just finished converting a repository in which Q only had one subdirectory, and the solution there was easy. `rename C/ .` in a --filemap option, but that fails rather dramatically for this case (the Q branch interleaves C and D).

Ideally, I could simply ignore Q entirely in one pass, and then do a second conversion with the convert.svn.branches option set to branches/Q, but I cannot get the following syntax in the filemap to work:

```
exclude "Q C D"
```

nor

```
exclude "C D"
```

My hope was that excluding C and D would prevent any files from being imported on that branch, and since I have a specified filemap, the resulting empty commits would be removed. I can't get the exclude directive to exclude any directories, no matter the various syntax options I've tried.

Edit: The end result I'd like to have is a mercurial repo with trunk as the normal tip, and named branches A, B, C and D... that silly Q thing can just go away during the conversion, if I can figure out how.

Comment: I'm sorry, exactly what is it that you are trying to accomplish? What is the final result that you want? What conversion tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason when I tried this yesterday, it wasn't working, but today it works...

a filemap of

```
exclude "C"
exclude "D"
```

seems to be working properly now... I'm having an odd issue with the first conversion I'm doing crashing, but that's an issue to take up with the devs (unrelated)